# Unable to find link (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, saas

I have problem:

```
When I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"                         #   
features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
Unable to find link "Find Movies With Same Director" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

in web_steps.rb:

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end
```

in my routes:

```
find_movies_with_same_director_movie GET    /movies/:id/find_movies_with_same_director(.:format) {:action=>"find_movies_with_same_director", :controller=>"movies"}
                              movies GET    /movies(.:format)
```

in my view show.html.haml:

```
%br
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director',  find_movies_with_same_director_movie_path(@movie)
```

in controller movies_controller.rb:

```
def find_movies_with_same_director
  # some code
end
```

What wrong?

Comment: Are you on the right page when you look to click this link?

Comment: `code` Scenario: find movie with same director
  Given I am on the details page for "Star Wars"
  When  I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"`code`

Comment: that doesn't answer the question. Use `save_and_open_page` just before the failing step to make sure you're on the right page.

Comment: Yes.You are right. save_and_open_page - open index page, but i don't understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks sevenseacat for hint: save_and_open_page

I have Scenario:

```
Scenario: find movie with same director
Given I am on the details page for "Star Wars"
When  I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"
```

In step: Given I am on the details page for "Star Wars"
I have mistake:

```
when /^the details page for "(.*)"$/       
  movies_path(Movie.find_by_title($1))
```

Right path:

```
when /^the details page for "(.*)"$/       
  movie_path(Movie.find_by_title($1))
```